# Get names and record counts for .txt files in a folder

Tags: export, sas, text-files

I have exported SAS datasets into .txt files. How do I get the names and record counts of all these text files? This is to create a table/report that will show which SAS datasets got exported to text files and how many records each text file has. I know how to do something similar if these files are SAS datasets but I cannot find anything on .txt files.

The export procedure in SAS generates the result of the export and the # of records in each file. But I am doing the export for multiple files across 40-50 countries. So I cannot look at each line of the export log to determine name and record counts for multiple files. And opening each file to get record counts is not an option here :)

I need to have a report, preferably in a table format that list the names of the exported text files and the record counts for each file.

Thanks Chris, for your suggestion and code. But there is no master dataset. Let me explain my question again:

```
Country A has 10 different SAS datasets - Adata01.sas7bdat....Adata10.sas7bdat
Country B has 15 different SAS datasets - Bdata02.sas7bdat...Bdata15.sas7bdat
...and so on.
```

I need to export each of these datasets into a text file with UTF8 encoding - which I have done. So, now I have:

```
Country A - Adata01.txt, Adata02.txt....Adata10.txt
Country B - Bdata02.txt, Bdata03.txt...Bdata15.txt
```

An option I can think of is - scan the export log and just extract the name of the text file and # of records written to the text file. What I want is something like:

```
Sas Data          Exported   Text Data     # of Records
Adata01.sas7bdat  Yes        Adata01.txt   8000
```

Any good approach for doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're willing to accept SAS's word for how many records it put out (ie, trust the log), you can parse the log.  Below is an example; it may or may not work for your exact circumstances, but it should be a useful guide.

```
proc printto log="d:\temp\log.txt" new; *put log out to a file somewhere;
run;
 *here is your proc export;
proc export data=sashelp.class outfile="d:\temp\test.txt" dbms=tab replace;
run;
proc printto;
run;

data log_parse;
infile "d:\temp\log.txt"; *your log file;
input @;                  *open for input;
if find(_infile_,'were written') then do;  *if we are on the right line;
    input
        @"NOTE: " records                 /*@"str" is a useful kind of input here */
        @"the file " filename :$50.       /*"the file " is in case you have 'file' in your filename.  You may want to parse this further (for example, remove quotes)*/
        ;
    output;
end;
run;
```

Comment: Note that this assumes you need the number of lines actually written out; the number of records (in SAS) is available in _EFIREC_ automatic macro variable.  You can potentially use this as a comparison if you save it after each export.

Comment: This may work - let me do some changes and get back to you. Thanks Joe!

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with SAS datasets, however, here are some ideas assuming you can't get the export details from within SAS.  But hopefully, that info is available and someone will tell you how to get it.

If not here is a very simple solution:
If the export consists of 1 row of data per item, just open the file and get a count the number of lines.
To get a count of the # of exported datasets, use a temp folder for the exports and then get a count of the files in the folder.  As you count them, move them to the folder where people expect them (so you don't count them twice).

With this, you have the name of each export file, the # of lines per file (i.e. exported item count), the location (since you moved it out of the temp, you know where you moved it), and how many were exported in the process.

I made some simple assumptions here.  Assuming that none of the above are appropriate, post a little more details and you will get more suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Why not take the # records from the SAS dataset(s) which create the text files?

Assuming you export all the records per country into each countries text file, you can simply do a `proc freq` by country on your master dataset. This will give the # records in each countries output file.

```
/* Generate counts by country */
proc freq data=master noprint ;
  table COUNTRY /out=f_countries ;
run ;

data _null_ ;
  set f_countries end=eof ;
  call symputx(cats('CTRY',_n_),COUNTRY) ;
  if eof then call symputx('CTRYN',_n_) ;
run ;

%MACRO EXPORT_LOOP ;
  %DO I = 1 %TO &CTRYN ;
    proc export data=master (where=(COUNTRY="&&CTRY&I")) outfile="c:\Country &&CTRY&I...txt" dbms=tab ;
    run ;
  %END ;
%MEND ;

%EXPORT_LOOP ;

title "Record counts by Country, output file = c:\Country <country>.txt" ;
proc report data=f_countries ;
run ;
```

Comment: The export or conversion may have caused truncation or other inconsistencies as I am doing an UTF-8 encoding on the text files. That's the reason I need to get the record counts from the text files.

Comment: The SAS log will indicate the number of records written to the text file, which is the same as the # input records from the SAS dataset. I don't think this will reflect any encoding 'inconsistencies'. The only way to do what you ask is to read the text files back into SAS.

Comment: @rom Are you willing to trust SAS that it put out the rows it says (ie, if you could read the log, you would believe the information in it)?

Comment: @Joe, that will work if I can extract the name of the text file and # of records from the export log. What do you suggest for doing that?